# Autostart C++ win32 console application in XPe

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, autostart

I have a Win32 Console Application which I would like XPe to autostart when the system boots up.

What i have done currently is to put this app path in the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run.

However, it does not seem to work with console applications? as i have tried with GUI apps and it works.

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding `start /D <absolute_path_to_your_exe> <executable>` to your `Run` or `AutoRun` section.

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps this link could help: http://ask-leo.com/auto_start_how_do_i_run_a_program_automatically_when_windows_starts.html

Comment: Just interesting for me: must your program start for every user? if not, use CURRENT_USER section - because IMO you should have admin rights to be able to write in LOCAL_MACHINE section.

Comment: I've added to Run section with start /D but it doesn't work

Comment: @user990639 - Have you tried adding a shortcut to you program under the `AutoStart` folder in the start menu?

Comment: Actually there is no multiple users for the system. Just the Admin and so the program should just start whenever the system boots up.

Comment: @KristerAndersson When i put the program shortcut to AutoStart folder the console program will run. Thanks! But just curious as to why i cannot put it in the registry?

Comment: @user990639 - I guess you could check your eventlog and see if it tells you something about why the application isn't starting when you add it into the `Run` section.

Comment: @user990639 - Would be nice if you showed the complete command you are trying to add to the registry.

Comment: @KristerAndersson For the GUI app, I just create a New->String Value. The name i just put FilePath, the value: C:\Test\WindowsApplication1.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Task Scheduler. 0123456789

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment you could add a shortcut to the application under the `AutoStart` folder in the start menu.

From the help for the `start` command:

> When executing an application that is a 32-bit GUI application,
>   CMD.EXE
>       does not wait for the application to terminate before returning to
>       the command prompt.  This new behavior does NOT occur if executing
>       within a command script.

So it seems like starting a 32-bit non-GUI application would wait for the application to terminate unless you would place a call to it inside a batch file or similar and then in turn call start on that batch script instead.

Try creating a file named something like `your-app.bat` and add the following command inside it:

```
 start /D "C:\Test\" WindowsApplication1.exe
```

Then in your registry point to your newly created batch script instead of the actual executable.